# удаляется пользователь при выборе нет или да

Tags: php, sql

Есть форма

```
    <h1>Вы уверены что хотите удалить этого пользователя!</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" style="text-align:center;">
        <label><input type="radio" name="yn" value="yes"/>Да</label>
        <label><input type="radio" checked name="yn" value="no"/>Нет</label>    </br>
        <input type="submit" name="vse" value="Подтвердить"/>
    </form>
```

вот PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['vse'])){
    if(isset($_POST['yn'])=='yes'){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
        header("location:home.php?id=".$id);
    }elseif(isset($_POST['yn'])=='no'){
        echo "asd";
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что при нажатии на радиокнопку НЕТ, пользователь всеравно удаляется(

Comment: Понимаю, буквы платные, но уж раскошельтесь в местах типа ключей параметров, а то при тимлид при CodeReview Вас шваброй погонит. Как и за "vse".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Верным будет следующее решение:

```
if(isset($_POST['vse']) && isset($_POST['yn'])){
    if($_POST['yn']=='yes'){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
        header("location:home.php?id=".$id);
    }elseif($_POST['yn']=='no'){
        echo "asd";
    }
}
```

---

А теперь самое интересное:
 
**Давайте разберёмся почему у вас срабатывало условие!**

```
if(isset($_POST['yn'])=='yes'){}
```

Скорее всего Вы хотели чтобы условие сработало если в массиве `$_POST` есть значение с ключом `"yn"` и что оно равно `"yes"`.

По факту это две проверки и результатом должно было логичкое сложение двух булевых значений.
Для этого используется оператор `&&`, он будет возвращать `true` когда значение справа и слева тоже равны `true`.
Верным способом сделать это было бы получить поочередно два булевыых значения, а потом уже получить их сумму и её подставлять в условие.
Для понимания я вывел по одной операции на одн строку:

```
$is_set = isset($_POST['yn']); 
$is_positive = ($_POST['yn']=='yes');
$result = $is_set && $is_positive;
if($result){ }
```

Или всё тоже самое, но только без временных переменных и в одну строку

```
if(isset($_POST['yn']) && ($_POST['yn']=='yes')){ }
```

Я для того, чтобы не писать два раза проверку `isset($_POST['yn'])` вынес её на уровень выше.

**С верным решением то всё понятно - почему тем не менее срабатывало условие в примере?!**

Также пошагово разберём Ваш пример:

```
if(isset($_POST['yn'])=='yes'){}
```

1. Сначала Вы проверяете наличие поля в массиве( `isset($_POST['yn'])` ).
   При проверке через данную форму оно в любом случае будет равно `true`
2. Далее Вы сравниваете полученное значение `true` со строкой
   И как странно это не прозвучит, но сравнение `true` со строкой 'yes' в результате вернёт `true`
   И условие срабатывает

**Разберём подробнее сравнение булева значения со строкой**
на самом деле там происходит не одна операция а две!
Так как изначально сравниваемые значения имеют разные типы данных, то они в итоге сводятся к одному типу.
php является (слабо-) или динамическитипизированным языком и это надо учитывать.

Перед тем как сравнить строку `"yes"` с булевым значением интерпретатор php приводит её к булеву типу.
И тут кроется ответ: **любая НЕПУСТАЯ строка приводится к `true`!**
`false` даёт при приведении только `""` или другими словами пустая строка!

Вот и получается, что Вы сравниваете

```
if(true == true){}
```

Что и даёт соответствующий результат!

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $_POST['yn'] == 'yes' ){
...
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['vse'])){
    if($_POST['yn']=='yes'){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
        header("location:home.php?id=".$id);
    }else{
        echo "asd";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Перепише второй if как

```
if (isset($_GET['smth'] ) && $_GET['smth'] == 'yes')
```

Comment: Не помогло, все равно удаляет даже при выборе "нет"

Comment: Просто в примере указан массив `$_GET`,  а не `$_POST`

Comment: Да, я писал Post но что то тоже